# matlab determine if cells array is a row

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a data:

```
data = 

{1x6 cell}    {1x6 cell}
```

I want to know if data{2:end} is a row, so I used:

```
stop = 0;
for (k=2:length(data))
    if isrow(data{k})
         stop = 1;
    end
end
```

but, the function 'isrow' doesn't work for arguments of type 'cell'.

I read about it, and there is a function: 'cell2struct':

```
structArray = cell2struct(cellArray, fields, dim);
```

but I don't think that I will be able to use that, because I have to give 'fields' and 'dim' to this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see what the problem is here. This is what I get on R2010b:

```
>> data = {cell(1,6) cell(1,6) cell(3,6)}
data = 
    {1x6 cell}    {1x6 cell}    {3x6 cell}

>> isrow(data{2})
ans =
     1

>> isrow(data{3})
ans =
     0
```

Comment: maybe because I have 2010 a :/

Comment: Perhaps you could try `size()` instead.

Comment: thank you, I check if size(data{k},1) < size(data{k},2) to determine if it is a row or col. if it's equal, it doesnt interesting me. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to check it in another way:

```
  function bIsRow = isrow(x)
      bIsRow = (size(x,2) == numel(x));
  end
```

Comment: I think it doesn't work :/ if I have data = 

{1x6 cell}    {6x1 cell} so bIsRow = 1 for both data (data{1} and data{2})

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if isrow(cell2mat(data{k}))
```

Comment: thank you, but I gor an error:
 ??? Undefined function or method 'isrow' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for `isrow()`

```
function Y = isrow(X)
%
% ISROW    True for row vectors.
%
%   Y = ISROW(X) returns logical 1 if X is a row vector, 0 otherwise.
%   ISROW returns 1 for scalars also.
%
%    See also: ISCOL.
%

if ndims(X)==2 & size(X,1)==1 & size(X,2)>=1
   Y = logical(1);
else
   Y = logical(0);
end
```

[Source via MATLAB Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1309-general-extra-toolbox/content/isrow.m)